# "Well said" synonym

Tags: meaning, word-usage

I was wondering, if instead of "well said" I can say "I love how you put it into words" or "I love the way you said it"? I get the feeling that "put into words" is mostly used as an expression of romantic love, like: " I love you so much that I cannot put it into words" and I don't want to write a love letter...

Comment: You can certainly say *I love how you put it into words*, but it would not have the same meaning as *well said.*

Answer (score 3):

I don't agree that the expression "put into words" is predominantly an expression of romantic love. If anything in your example sentence "*I love how you put it into words...*" hints at it being romantic I would say it is the word "*love*"!

If you want to tell somebody that you appreciated the way they phrased something, you could say:

> I *like* the way you *expressed* that

or

> I like your choice of words

or

> I like the way you phrased that

Alternatives to "like" might be:

- appreciate
- identified with

The expression "well said" does not always denote an appreciation for someone's phraseology. It is also used to show appreciation for, or agreement with the *sentiments* contained in a person's words.